# NumPy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract the second and the 3rd to the fifth columns of the NumPy array, how would I go about it?

```
A = array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6]])
A[:, [1, 4:6]]
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you -- it's usually a good idea to explicitly specify the output you want, because it's not obvious -- you could use [numpy.r_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
In [27]: A
Out[27]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6]])

In [28]: A[:, [1,3,4,5]]
Out[28]: 
array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 7, 4, 5]])

In [29]: A[:, r_[1, 3:6]]
Out[29]: 
array([[1, 3, 4, 5],
       [5, 7, 4, 5]])

In [37]: A[1:, r_[1, 3:6]]
Out[37]: array([[5, 7, 4, 5]])
```

which you can then flatten or reshape as you like.  `r_` is basically a convenience function to generate the right indices, e.g.

```
In [30]: r_[1, 3:6]
Out[30]: array([1, 3, 4, 5])
```

Comment: Quick question, why is the index array not inclusive?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

```
In [10]: A[1:, [1]+range(3,6)]
Out[10]: array([[5, 7, 4, 5]])
```

Note this gives you the second, fourth, fifth and six columns of all rows but the first.

Answer (score 0):

The second element is `A[:,1]`. Elements 3-5 (I'm assuming you want inclusive) are `A[:,2:5]`. You won't be able to extract them with a single call. To get them as an array, you could do

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6]])
my_cols = np.hstack((A[:,1][...,np.newaxis], A[:,2:5]))
```

The `np.newaxis` stuff is just to make `A[:,1]` a 2D array, consistent with `A[:,2:5]`.

Hope this helps.